# "Sorry about that" - Usage

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

A few months ago, I was down with jaundice, and when I let my friend know about it, he sent me a text saying "**Sorry** about the jaundice", expressing sympathy. Like this one incident, we frequently encounter sympathy messages starting with "sorry". I am curious where did the *sorry* originate from? Why do they say *sorry*? It's not their fault that I am having a bad time. Or is it that they want to apologize on behalf of the entire mankind and nature that have played out in a way which caused the loss to an individual—in my case, caused me jaundice. Pardon me if this question is too basic for this community.

Comment: ***Sorry (adj.)** 
Old English sarig "distressed, grieved, full of sorrow" (not found in the physical sense of "sore"), from Proto-Germanic *sairiga- "painful" ***Apologetic sense (short for I'm sorry) is attested from 1834; phrase sorry about that popularized 1960s by U.S. TV show "Get Smart."***: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sorry&searchmode=none

Comment: In this sense "sorry" is expressing sympathy.  The speaker feels sorrow upon learning of your illness, loss, etc.    "Sorry" in the apologetic sense is really the oddball here.

Answer (score 1):

[Oxford Online Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sorry) has the following definition:

> Feeling sad or distressed ***through sympathy*** with someone
>   else’s misfortune: *I was sorry to hear about what happened to your
>   family*

[Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sorry&searchmode=none) states that the word was used in Old English that means:

> Old English sarig "***distressed, grieved, full of sorrow***" (not
>   found in the physical sense of "sore")...***Apologetic sense*** (short for I'm sorry) is attested from 1834; phrase sorry about that popularized 1960s by U.S. TV show "Get Smart." Related: Sorrily; sorriness.

It doesn't mean someone is apologizing for anything. He is just feeling sympathy (or sorrow/pity) for what happened to you.

Answer (score 0):

*"I'm sorry about ...*" means that "***I am sad, distressed, full of sorrow to know of..***"

Comment: This post would be improved by giving evidence for this usage, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  A simple "Sorry" means exactly the same.

Comment: @Chenmunka - Yes, my answer does answer the OP.  And no, "*Sorry*!" is not the same as "I'm sorry about ..." .  A simple "Sorry!" is an apology to someone for something you've done to them.  With 'sorry' you  acknowledge responsibility for a bad thing and are expressing a wish to make it better (e.g. I say sorry if I bump into  someone accidentally).  "*I'm sorry about*..."(e.g. the jaundice (OP)) lets someone know that I understand something is not good for them, and that I am suffering because they are suffering. It does NOT mean that I am responsible for their bad situation.

Answer (score 0):

"Sorry about that."  Apology?  I think not.  "Sorry about that" was originated in the 1960's television sitcom, "Get Smart."  Maxwell Smart used the phrase all the time and it has (unfortunately) been part of our lexicon ever since.  At best, it is expressing pity or concern that something bad happened to another person, but it is not an apology.  At worst, it is a sarcastic utterance that implies that nothing worthy of apologizing for ever happened.

Comment: The phrase was in use long before the 1960's. But that TV series might have given it a boost -- see what [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorry+about+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csorry%20about%20that%3B%2Cc0) has to say.

Comment: My recollection is that Maxwell Smart often used "Sorry about that" in situations where an apology (not just pity or concern) would be expected.

Answer (score -1):

The term "sorry about that" is one of my two least favorite sayings ~ it is usually said by the unremorseful person who caused the problem to the person affected by the problem which tells the affected person "tough excrement" and/or "get over yourself."

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. We run a question and answer site, not a regular chat forum for expressing opinions. What you have written does not answer the question, it would have been better suited to being a comment, you will be able to leave those on other's posts as soon as you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score -2):

*Why do they say sorry?*

Personally, I never say sorry at all - in fact I never apologise.  I learnt this from a wise sailor in the mid 1970s - he owned restaurants in San Diego, and he didn't say sorry either.

It's not out of arrogance or an uncaring nature ... but if there is an issue, there are three things available to you: (1) address the problem as effectively and as efficiently as you can, (2) advise the complainant that nothing can be done to solve it ("There is no lobster available ... can I offer you something else at no charge?"), or (3) advise the complainant that while you might sympathise, it really is not your problem.

One of these three responses will resolve things - saying "sorry" makes you feel bad, it makes the recipient of the sorry feel bad, and worse, it can often be a substitute for actually finding a solution to the problem.

So my advice - avoid sorry and avoid apologies ... just solve stuff you can, and avoid stuff you cannot. "Sorry" really is a dreadfully overworked word in all Western societies.

Comment: I don't think the word ***sorry*** in the OP's question has anything to do with ***apologizing***.

Comment: Besides, since *Love Story* there's been no need to say you're sorry.